# Problem creating file on samba file server

Tags: smb

When I try to recreate a file on smb server which was deleted from same client machine few moments ago, it gives error. What could be reason for that? No other client is accessing that file.

This problem is not always reproducible, however can be reproduced now and then.

Client is mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `smb.conf` of the samba setup. It's possible to have delete access but not create access.